# How to not evaluate expressions in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want a directive to have a "template" attribute which would take a value and use it later as a template. However if the attribute value contains an angular expression it is evaluated as soon as the directive is used. Is it possible to disable expression evaluation for an attribute?

Example ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pyp1C1ORP094syJAYZoc)):

```html
<my-directive template-attribute="my name is: {{ name }}"></my-directive>
```

```js
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {

    },
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      $scope.name = 'Filip';

      $attrs.$observe('templateAttribute', function (value) {
        $scope.templateAttribute = value;
      });
    },
    template: '<div>Template with expression: <strong>{{ templateAttribute }}</strong></div>'
  };
});
```

I could imagine using some sort of escaping:

```html
<my-directive template-attribute="my name is: \{\{ name \}\}"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would want this.  `ng-include` or transclude provide other ways to dynamically change the template.

Comment: It's possible to use [ngNonBindable](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) for an element, but if you want this for only 1 attribute, it seems complicated.

Comment: I'm loading html snippet which contains ng-controller and I need to configure scope of that controller per AJAX request. Controller code is defined in external js file so the only way to configure the scope I figured out is a custom "ng-init" directive placed inside the controller which basically does initialisation of its parent scope (controller's scope). Everything works fine until a scope variable contains angular expressions (for example ng-grid allows to configure cell template by setting the template as a specific scope variable).